# using IEnumerable value for autocomplete results are always null

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I have the following  fields in my View Model and I'm trying to use it in a autocomplete and in case the value does not exist  add new value to table.

How ever the value passed to controller is always `null`.

I think the problem is here

> "@Html.TextBoxFor(**m=>m.Genres**,new { @class = "form-control" ,@id= "term" }) "

I need to get the **.Name** property . I prefer not to change my VM.

```
public class LectureFormViewModel
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
       //Values 
        public byte Genre { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
}

public JsonResult GetGenresName(string term)
{
    var genre = _context.Genres
        .Where(gn => term == null ||
         gn.Name.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower())).Select(x => new
         { id = x.Id, value = x.Name }).Distinct().ToList();
    return Json(genre, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}



@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "VoosUp", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "RestoForm"}))
{
    //values
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.Genre, new {@class = "control-label"})
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Genres, new {@class = "form-control", @id = "term"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Genres)
    </div>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right" onclick="GetLocation()" value="Finish"/>
}

@section scripts
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <script>
        $("#term").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetGenresName", "VoosUp")',

                    data: "{'GetGenresName': '" + request.term + "' }",

                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: "POST",

                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataFilter: function(data) { return data; },
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(term),
                            console.debug();
                        response($.map(data,
                            function(item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.value,
                                    value: item.value,
                                    id: item.id
                                }
                            }));
                    }
                });

            },
            minLength: 2
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary yes that true but my null value is in public JsonResult GetGenresName(string term)//Nulll the problem is here : @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Genres it should get the Name value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are binding the textbox with `IEnumerable<Genre>` type property and your controller action expects a parameter of type `string`, you should be using a string type property for mapping the textbox value to controller action, another thing is that the textbox name will be used for model binding at post, and you will have html generated for textbox like:

```
<input type="text" name="Genres" ................... />
```

But in controller action you are parameter name `term` that would also not work, as the value will be posted in a parameter named `Genres`.

The solution is to add another property in your view model for textbox binding like:

```
public class LectureFormViewModel
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Term {get;set;}
        public byte Genre { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
}
```

Now in your view, bind the TextBox with the Term property :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Term, new {@class = "form-control"})
```

and in controller action parameter name will be `Term` now:

```
public JsonResult GetGenresName(string Term)
{
}
```