# Autocomplete in C# using typeahead not working

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

My JS function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#pName").autocomplete({
                source: '@Url.Action("GetExistingProducts")'
            });
        });
</script>
```

ID `#pName` is the id of the textbox which is in a **Modal**.

My `GetExistingProducts` function in the controller

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetExistingProducts()
{
    return _traceProjectService.GetAllProducts();
}
```

This makes a call to `GetAllProducts()` in my service

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetAllProducts()
{
      var productList = myContext.Projects.Select(x =>x.ProductName).ToList();
      return productList;    
}
```

**Issue:**

My JS function is not showing the existing Products when I start typing in my textbox.

References:

1. http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Would appreciate if some could tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: are there any errors in console? Put breakpoint in you server method is it called? what does it return?

Comment: @Rafal: Well I debugged the code. NO errors. It successfully returns the list of products from my service to my controller.

Comment: @PriyankaDembla Nice..You convert the result to the JSON Format.. 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41321959/using-ienumerable-value-for-autocomplete-results-are-always-null

Comment: @ManojMaharana: Converted to Json. Didn't help. If you could kindly edit my controller method in an answer, maybe I'll understand better and pick up from there.

Comment: @Could anybody help me out please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap3-typeahead.js"></script>

<script>

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetExistingProducts", "Admin")',
        type: "GET"
    }).done(function(dt) {
        var res = dt.split(",");
        $(".pText").typeahead({
            source: res,
            showHintOnFocus: "all",
            fitToElement: true
        });
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetExistingVersions", "Admin")',
        type: "GET"
    }).done(function(dt) {
        var res = dt.split(",");
        $(".vText").typeahead({
            source: res,
            showHintOnFocus: "all",
            fitToElement: true
        });
    });


</script>
```

On controller side

```
public string GetExistingProducts()
        {
            var x = yourservice.function().toList();
            string a = string.Empty;
            foreach (var item in x)
            {
                a += item + ",";
            }

            return a;


        }
```